Canon 1DS Mkii image fails to write to card
this is my first forum post so please bear with me.
I recently bought a second hand 1Ds Mkii. The camera seemd to function normally for a few months until it suddenly failed to take a photo, the issue is described below.
I can turn on the camera, view photo's on the card, navigate the menus, and change shutter/aperture/ISO/drive mode autofocus etc without any issues.
If I press the shutter, I can hear the mirror flick up and the shutter activate. I have tested this by setting a longer shutter speed of 10s and listening to the camera. Initially after pressing the shutter I can hear a click and again after 10 seconds I can hear another click.
The issue is that after the photo has been taken the camera becomes completely unresponisve, the card access light is constant red. None of the buttons do anything including the off switch (the only way to turn off the camera is by removing the battery).
The photo never gets written to the card and other photo's remain unaffected.
The problem seems to be mostly in the cold in temperatures around 0deg Celcius. This issue is unpredictable. I am using sandisk extreme 16GB sd card. I have tried using a Sandisk extreme CFexpress card with the same results. Formatting the card in camera, or creating a new folder seems to help sometimes.
Is this a common/obvious issue.
Any help would be appreciated

When you format the card, do you do it in camera using the camera's menu or using another device, like a computer?

Hi, thanks for replying. I format the card in the camera menu.

Freezing point is at the extreme lower limit of the camera's official operating temperature range. It's not certain that there is not some other issue, but you are at or beyond the official limit. One possible reason is electrolytic capacitors drying out with age, but it's by no means certain that that applies here.
It's worth also noting that the specified upper temperature of 45°C is lower than what can be occasionally experienced in real-world locations and conditions. I've been at just under 55°C in Death Valley and in enclosed sun soaked locations you can reach or exceed that.
Specification including the following on Canon US site here

The Canon EOS 1Ds Mark II has a working temperature range of 0°C–45°C (32°F–113°F),


Thank you, I hadn’t considered the caps, I might open it up and have a look.
